# AFNetworking Incompatible block pointer types sending

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, asihttprequest

I am using AFNetworking to access a URL with Windows Authentication. I was using ASIHTTPRequest to login like so:

```
-(BOOL)User:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kIP];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setUseSessionPersistence:YES];
    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:NO];
    [request setUsername:user];
    [request setPassword:password];
    [request setDomain:@"domain"];
    [request startSynchronous];

    NSError *loginError = [request error];
    if(loginError == nil){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

and now I am trying to do the same thing with AFNetworking and this what I came up with from this example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18385

```
-(BOOL)User:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kIP];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:90.0];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[@"domain" stringByAppendingString:user]
                                                        password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone]];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];


    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        return true;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        return false;

    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

but this gives me two errors:

```
/Users/jsuske/Documents/SSiPad(Device Only)ios7/SchedulingiPadApplication/Classes/LHJSonData.m:148:46: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'int (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *__strong, __strong id)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *__strong, __strong id)'

/Users/jsuske/Documents/SSiPad(Device Only)ios7/SchedulingiPadApplication/Classes/LHJSonData.m:152:15: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'int (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *__strong, NSError *__strong)'
```

How Can I create a method that will use user and password to login and store those credentials...this is possible with AFNetworking, it sure was with ASIHTTPRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are [misunderstanding blocks](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9438/how-to-use-blocks-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2). You are returning `TRUE`/`FALSE` from the callback blocks, **not** your method. Those blocks will be executed at some point in the future, and their return type is `void`. Try running this code to see the order:

```
-(void)User:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password
{
    // construct your request

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"In success block");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"In Fail block");
    }];
    [operation start];

    NSLog(@"Network op started");
}
```

As to your design, I would not return true or false, you have to find another way to manage the success and fail scenarios, which *could* look something like this (I don't know enough about your overall design to give a definitive answer):

```
-(void)User:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password
{
    // construct your request

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // called at somepoint in the future if the request is success full
        [weakSelf handleSuccess:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // called at somepoint in the future if the request fails
        [weakSelf handleFail:error];
    }];
    [operation start];
}

- (void)handleSuccess(id)response {
    // process the response
}

- (void) handleFail:(NSError*)error {
    // evaluate error
}
```

You see the bock declaration here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.h