# Objective C Incompatible block pointer types sending

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm using parse 1.7.4 , this is y code :

```
+(NSArray *)getCategorieFromParse{



    PFQuery *categoriesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Categorie"]; 

    [categoriesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){ 

        if (!error) 

            return objects; 

        else 

            return [[NSArray alloc] init]; 

    }]; 




}
```

but this is generate this error :

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSArray *(^)(NSArray
>   *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'PFArrayResultBlock __nullable' (aka 'void (^)(NSArray * __nullable
>   __strong, NSError * __nullable __strong)')

At the return line

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate here. Different framework, same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/q/29500188/620197

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your block wasn't declared with a return type, and it returns an NSArray*, there it is a block returning an NSArray*. The method you are calling expects a block returning void. Obviously your block is not acceptable.

I suspect there is some deep misunderstanding going on what this block is supposed to do. Your method getCategorieFromParse *cannot* return an array. It's sending an asynchronous request, and your callback block will be called long after getCategorieFromParse returns. The callback block shouldn't try to return anything; it's job is to process the array that it was given.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return values from within a code block. You should rather use a [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers) (just an example I found on google) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You make asynchronous calls. You can't return array synchronously.

Solution: make your method also asynchronous:

```
+(void) getCategorieFromParse:(void (^)(NSArray*))completion
{
    PFQuery *categoriesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Categorie"]; 

    [categoriesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){ 

        if (!error) 

           completion(objects); 

        else 

           completion([[NSArray alloc] init]); 

    }]; 
}
```